# apply function with implicit parameter requires explicit argument

Tags: scala, implicit

I can't figure out why this does not work:

```
case class Expression extends Node[Doube] {

   def apply(implicit symbolTable: Map[String,Double]) = value
}
```

note that value is defined in Node, also with an implicit symbol table argument.

When I try to invoke it like so:

```
implicit val symbolTable = Map("a"->1, "b"->2)
//and x is an Expression, then:

x() // does not compile (can't find implicit) but 
x(symbolTable) // works fine
```

and strangely:

```
x.value // works fine too
```

if I write apply like so:

```
def apply()(implicit symbolTable: Map[String,Double])
```

it works, but I don't understand why I need to do that....

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#implicit-conversions) distinguishes value conversions from method conversions.

`x` is a value. For your example with two param lists, `x()` is a method type with one param list, the implicit one, which is supplied implicitly.

For your original example, with one implicit param list, `x()` fails to supply a required arg. (Not "implicit not found.")

```
scala> def f(implicit s: String) = 42
f: (implicit s: String)Int

scala> f
<console>:9: error: could not find implicit value for parameter s: String
              f
              ^

scala> f()
<console>:9: error: not enough arguments for method f: (implicit s: String)Int.
Unspecified value parameter s.
              f()
               ^
```

For the implicits to be supplied, you must not supply the param list.

For your strange `x.value`, obviously `value` is a method with one implicit param list.

More:

```
scala> object x { def apply(implicit s: String) = 42 }
defined object x

scala> x.apply
<console>:9: error: could not find implicit value for parameter s: String
              x.apply
                ^

scala> implicit val s: String = "hi"
s: String = hi

scala> x.apply
res1: Int = 42

scala> x()
<console>:10: error: not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit s: String)Int in object x.
Unspecified value parameter s.
              x()
               ^
```

When you write `x.apply` as above, it will either supply parens to turn it into an application, supplying implicit args, or try to turn it into a function if the context wants that.

Comment: yes, value is a method with one implicit parameter list, but so is apply, why do they not behave the same way?

Comment: You didn't write `x.apply` anywhere.

Comment: isn't that what x() invokes?

Comment: I mean you didn't write `x.apply`, which is not the same as writing `x.apply()` or `x()`. `x.apply` is a method, not a value. You get a value by adding parens `x.apply()` or `x.apply(_)` to get a function.